# Downloading SDK Applicasa iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, database, backend

Hi wondering if anyone else is using or has tried the back-end web service Applicasa. If so, could you explain how to properly import the SDK and framework?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Download the Framework and the SDK Files (Download SDK Button)

Then add the framework to your project (in your projects target->Build Phases ->Link Binary With Libaries-> + button -> Add Other
After that in Build Setting, search for "Other Linker Flags" and add "-ObjC -all_load")

SDK: Just drag the files into your project, and import the header.

Soon we will release a nice sample project.

If you have any other question just ask me at: benny@applicasa.com

Comment: At present applicasa use its own server to test WS. So it is neccesary that i must have to use your server for databse managment? How can i change the backed server from your server to my server?

Comment: I replied you to the email you sent me